# Error - __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python

I'm trying to initialize the class (extraropt) from another .py but it gives me an error, I've searched but I haven't found a solution.

Heres the code of the one py I'm calling from:

**main.py:**

```
class GameWindow(ui.ScriptWindow):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        import extraop

        exec 'extraop.extraropt().Show(stream)'
```

And here's the code of the one py I'm trying to call(init and del only):

**extraop.py**

```
class extraropt(ui.Window):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        ui.Window.__init__(self)
        self.BuildWindow()
        self.stream=stream
    def __del__(self):
        ui.Window.__del__(self)
```

It gives this error:

```
Error - __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. At what line do you get the error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Miguel! You may want to read over the FAQ on how to post a good question. We like to cut out the chatty behavior and get straight to the point, hence the edits. In addition, it is better if post a complete, minimal working example (including the full traceback for errors) so we can better help you.

Comment: Its fixed, it was on the __init__ of the extraop.py. line 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the line

```
exec 'extraop.extraropt().Show(stream)'
```

You are implicitly calling `extraropt.__init__()` by creating a new instance of `extraopt`. In your code, you show that `extraropt.__init__()` takes a second (`stream`) argument, so you have to pass that in.

```
extraop.extraropt(stream).Show()
```

Incidentally, there is no reason why you should be doing an `exec` rather than explicitly calling it as I did above. There is also no reason for you to have a `__del__()` method defined as you only call the parent `__del__()` method anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You need to initialize the parent this way:

```
super(extraropt, self).__init__(stream)
```

Comment: Didnt do it but Joel Cornett got me what i wanted.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The `stream` variable in the line `exec 'extraop.extraropt().Show(stream)'` should be passed into the constructor of the `extraropt` class, like this:

```
exec 'extraop.extraropt(stream).Show()'
```